# Syntax for calling Watson API in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ibm-watson

What is the syntax for calling the watson visual recognition api in python?
I've looked around a lot but have not been able to find a proper syntax for the call of the api. What parameters have to be defined within the call of the api?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: First result for "watson visual recogition api python": https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/visual-recognition/api/v3/?python#classify_an_image Please do your own research before posting questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Python SDK that will help you call all the Watson APIs with a few lines of code.

Install the Python SDK by running

```
pip install watson-developer-cloud
```

Get an API Key from the [IBM Cloud](https://console.bluemix.net/catalog/services/visual-recognition)

Create a `main.py` file with the next snippet from the [API Reference](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/visual-recognition/api/v3/?python#classify_an_image) (Credits to @bailey Parker)

```
    import json
    from watson_developer_cloud import VisualRecognitionV3

    visual_recognition = VisualRecognitionV3('2016-05-20', api_key='{api_key}')

    with open('./yout-image-file.jpg', 'rb') as images_file:
        classes = visual_recognition.classify(
            images_file,
            parameters=json.dumps({ 'threshold': 0.6}))
    print(json.dumps(classes, indent=2))
```

Open a terminal and run:

```
python main.py
```